# Why is the folder size (in properties) different from the total file/folder sizes in the folder?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

**Here's my problem**

I'm trying to do a **cleanup of my hard drive**, and I'm constantly seeing this scenario:

(1) **Aggregate folder size**: I check the folder size viewing properties right clicking the folder

(2) **Individual folder/file sizes**: I check the individual file/folder sizes belonging to that folder viewing properties on the individual file/folder sizes, and then adding them up *(with hidden and system files shown).*

These two figures are always different, sometimes by a large margin.

For instance, my C drive now, by method (1), shows a consumed space of **42.4 GB**.

However, by method (2), by inspecting the respective files/folders, the total consumed space adds up only to **33.1 GB**. This is a **28% discrepancy** (over the smaller file size) and I have no idea where the rest of the space is going.

My hard drive is constantly in danger of being full (it's bootcamp on a mac with **50 GB** of partitioned space), and there's not much I've got installed in terms of software, nor do I have large media files like movies, downloads, temp files, application temp files, torrents, etc.

Most of it's just consumed by the files in C:/Windows, but last I checked, I don't know enough to know which files to delete, and I've heard that you really can't do anything about the space boggling **winsxs** and **system32**.

Can you guys recommend a starting point to free up disk space?

Thanks!!

Baggio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open Explorer and select properties, Windows reads the free space from the NTFS bitmap metafile. Selecting all files/folders in explorer and showing properties, scan all files/folders. But Windows skips here hidden files/folders and folders where your current user doesn't have read permissions (System Volume Information folder for example).

You should use [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) (run it as admin) to see which folders take most space:

[image]

Comment: excellent, will give it a shot, thanks for the advice :)