# Windows displays wrong used space data?

Tags: windows-7, windows

So I have a C: partition, and windows says that it has 92.5 GB worth of data in it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNItZ.png]

However I've selected every fodler in C: (including hidden folders), and clicked properties to check how much space does it take up, and it is just 57GB.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpm4T.png]

Now, is Windows displaying wrong information, or may I doing it wrong.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNItZ.png) Is the properties of C: where it shows how much of the disk is being used

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpm4T.png) Is the properties of all the files in C:

Comment: I was certain this had been asked, but can not find a duplicate...

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this could be caused by the [Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) feature of Windows 7?

Comment: Also see: [Why is the folder size (in properties) different from the total file/folder sizes in the folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/567175/why-is-the-folder-size-in-properties-different-from-the-total-file-folder-size?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 there we go! 
Also, I believe the drive properties dialog queries MFT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the remaining ~35G is occupied by [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) Have you had this option turned on? (It was ON by default I believe)

Comment: It is on, but shouldn't the copies be in one of those folders, and therefore listed when Windows calculates how much space it takes up?

Comment: Under normal user, you can't even access that directory

Comment: I'll try to do it with the account that has admnistrator's privileges

Comment: I've tried it, and the output is exactly the same

Comment: Are you sure you can access all files/directories under `C:\System Volume Information`?

Comment: I'll check that one individually

Comment: Even with the administrator's privileges, when I try to access it I get a access denied error. It probably is what's taking up the space. But I'd like to confirm it

Comment: If you really want to check, you can grant your username permission to access all subdirectories inside it. Look for Security Settings (or similar) tab under Directory Properties

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the C: drive and click properties, Windows is actually showing accurate information.

If you select all files in the C: drive, you actually don't. If you want to see all files in the C: drive, press Windows key + R, type in `cmd` then `cd C:` and finally `dir /a`. You will see all files and directories with their size.